# solving for $x$, $x$ on both sides

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have $7(3x+6) = 11-(x+2)$. I read about the thing where you put one part of the equation on both sides after simplifying a bit to something like $21x+42 = 11-(x+2)$, using the distributive property, it says.

Comment: It's impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would first distribute everything out on both sides to get

21x + 42 = 11 - x - 2

Combine your x terms on the left by adding the x from the right side.
Combine the independent numbers on the right by first subtracting 2 from 11 and then subtracting 42 from this result

22x = -33

Then divide -33 by 22

x = =33/22= -1.5

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know you could combine and divide like that.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a question there, but perhaps the answer to the question you failed to ask is: Add $x+2$ to both sides, and continue simplifying on the left-hand side.